# tm_polygons border.col should be defined by another variable using tmap package

Tags: r

I have this map below of life expectancy (lifeExp) across countries. I would like to overlay (simply add) GDP per capita (gdp_cap_est) as border line colors instead of the current green across all countries. That is the border line color for each country will be different depending on its GDP per capita range (group).
[image]

This is my sample code below. Thank you

```r
library(spData) # example datasets
library(tmap)   # map creation
library(sf)     # spatial data reprojection

world_moll = st_transform(world, crs = "+proj=moll")

tm_shape(world_moll) +
  tm_polygons(col = "lifeExp", border.col = "green") +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not readily possible as far as I know. Here is a workaround that's a bit hacky:

```
tm_shape(world_moll) +
    tm_fill(col = "gdpPercap") +
  tm_shape(st_buffer(world_moll, -7e4)) +
    tm_fill(col = "lifeExp") +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

Output (GDP is much lighter):

[image]